# My app needs time for initial startup

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an app which needs about a minute for initial startup. After that it takes just seconds. The reason for the long initial startup is that it needs to download financial data from Yahoo which I do not believe I have rights to redistribute.

Does this cause problems with the App Store?

I have written the app to work perfectly, so there is no issue of crashing or blocking the main thread. My question is whether anyone has dealt with submitting apps which takes time to startup. I have no (cheap) way of speeding it up.

Comment: As long as the UI isn't blocked during the minute you will be OK. Otherwise your app will be rejected because it will crash on startup.

Comment: That's if you're lucky, of course. If you're not, and for whatever reason it doesn't crash on startup while Apple's reviewing it, it *will* crash on startup for end users.

Comment: @rmaddy: what do you mean by "UI isn't blocked"? When it starts up it does not lock up resources.

Comment: If you do your data access on them main thread then your UI will be blocked. You must perform network access in a background thread.

Comment: @rmaddy: that's what I'm doing so it does not get killed by the OS. I fixed that issue a long time ago, just concerned about what reviewers might decided.

Answer (score 2):

from the [Apple guidlines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html):

> Apps are expected to launch and initialize themselves and start
>   handling events in less than 5 seconds. If an app does not finish its
>   launch cycle in a timely manner, the system kills it for being
>   unresponsive. Thus, any tasks that might slow down your launch (such
>   as accessing the network) should be executed asynchronously on a
>   secondary thread.

just try to put this logic out of initial startup. show some message inside the application about this and run the download process async.

Comment: My app does all that. I'm more concerned about what the App store reviewers might say. Are they okay with it?

Comment: it should be ok. just show a message that you download required date. it does make sense if you need to download some required data. use some good ui control to show the download progress (https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD for example)

Comment: @DmitryKhrukin: Yep, I did put a progress bar.